# How can I select a time range when some times are not allowed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile

I need some kind of control that will allow a user on a mobile device to select from available time ranges in a 24-hour period for a reservation manager.

For example, let's say the range starts at 8:00am.  A user cannot rent the space between 10:00am and 12:00pm (noon), and cannot rent the space between 3:00pm and 6:00pm.  Therefore, some valid rental ranges would be:

- 8:00am - 9:00am
- 8:00am - 10:00am
- 12:00pm - 3:00pm
- 1:00pm - 3:00pm
- 6:00pm - 7:00pm

You get the idea.

The problem is that I need to display to the user which range of times are already taken, and allow them to select a range of time from the available time slots.  My boss suggested using a range slider (such as [the jQuery one](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) or [the Telerik one](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/slider/examples/dragrange/defaultcs.aspx)), but none of the ones I've found seem to support this use-case.

I should note that my boss would really like to see this as a "timeline" for lack of a better word, where two slider bars represent the range and the slider line is colored red or green depending on whether that time is available.

Any suggestions?  Keep in mind that this is on a mobile device using ASP.NET MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to dynamically load the values using ajax when your control has focus and populate that control with the received values. In addition, you could use `Remote` attribute that would validate the selection against the available hours when a user makes a selection, just to be sure that another user did not make a reservation for the chosen time (so that you can avoid time clash).